# I'm trying to use structs' arrays but there's something wrong

Tags: c, struct

If I add just one player my program works as expected.

After the first cicle ends and it asks (in italian ) what i wanna do, if I give as input 1 it let me create a new player. Then it asks for the name and the lastname, but after it asks for the role type it blocks and it exits from the code.

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 25

struct rol{
    int position;
    int lato;
};
typedef struct rol role;

struct pl{
    role *ruol;
    int shirt_num;
    char name[20];
    char lastn[20];
};
typedef struct pl player;

struct tm{
    int classpos;
    int pnt;
    player players[MAX];
};


typedef struct tm team;

void define_role (role *ruolo);
void make_pl(player *pl);
void print_pl(player *pl,int i,role *x);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int risp,i;
    player *giocatore;
    int cont = 0;
    printf("Vuoi effettuare lavori su un giocatore o su una squadra ? \n [ 1) giocatore  2)  squadra] ");
    scanf(" %d",&risp);

    if(risp==1) {
        do {
            printf("\n\n1)Crea Giocatore \n 2)Modifica giocatore \n3)Inserisci giocatore in una squadra");
            printf("\n 4)Visualizza dati giocatore \n 5) Finish program");
            scanf(" %d",&risp);
            if(risp==1) {
                cont++;
                giocatore = (player*)malloc (cont*sizeof(player));
                if (giocatore== NULL) { 
            printf("Memory not allocated.\n"); 
            exit(0); 
            } 
                giocatore->ruol = (role*)malloc(cont*sizeof(role));
                if (giocatore->ruol== NULL) { 
            printf("Memory not allocated.\n"); 
            exit(0); 
            } 
                make_pl(&giocatore[cont-1]); //this is the main problem basically 
            }

            } while(risp != 5);
    }
    return 0;
}

void make_pl(player *pl) {
    printf("\n Inserisci nome ");
    scanf(" %s",pl->name);
    printf("\n Inserisci cognome ");
    scanf(" %s",pl->lastn);
    define_role(pl->ruol);
    printf("Inserisci numero di maglia ");
    scanf(" %d",&pl->shirt_num);
} 

void define_role(role *ruolo) {
    printf("\n Inserisci lato ");
    scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato);
    printf("\n Inserisci posizione ");
    scanf("%d",&ruolo->position);
}
```

this is what it show as output :

```
Vuoi effettuare lavori su un giocatore o su una squadra ? 
 [ 1) giocatore  2)  squadra] 1


1)Crea Giocatore 
 2)Modifica giocatore 
3)Inserisci giocatore in una squadra
 4)Visualizza dati giocatore 
 5) Finish program 
1

 Inserisci nome bobby

 Inserisci cognome solo

 Inserisci lato 0

 Inserisci posizione 1
Inserisci numero di maglia 15


1)Crea Giocatore 
 2)Modifica giocatore 
3)Inserisci giocatore in una squadra
 4)Visualizza dati giocatore 
 5) Finish program
1

 Inserisci nome robert

 Inserisci cognome idunno

 Inserisci lato 1

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 45s)
```

So the basic problem is I can't save more than one player. I'm kinda disperate and I don't know what's the problem .

Comment: To add a player, you probably want to use [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) and not `malloc`.

Comment: Also, `giocatore->ruol = (role*)malloc(cont*sizeof(role));` should probably be `giocatore[count-1]->ruol = (role*)malloc(cont*sizeof(role));`

Comment: ohh maybe you right . so i should malloc(0) to initialize the pointers and then reallocate the space with realloc (cont,sizeof(struct_variable) . Imma try that and tell if it works

Comment: You can pass a `NULL` pointer to `realloc` and it will behave like `malloc`. So just initialize the pointer to `NULL`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so basically i can allocate memory for every index i give to the array? Like if i wanna allocate one space at giocatore[10] it takes the first value of the array[10] and it allocates the memory of bytes (with the sizeof command )i need

Comment: @JhonnyMopp I tried with your changes it still stops at the same point